# Use the code below to query the count of forward citation, but it did't work

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-patent-search

I use the code below to query the count of forward citation, but it did't work.independent-tea-223707:Mypatent.publication_num_assignee is a table created by myself.

```
 SELECT c.publication_number AS Pub, COUNT(p.publication_number) AS
    CitedBy 
    FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p, UNNEST(citation) AS c 
    WHERE c.publication_number IN  (SELECT publication_number FROM `independent-tea-223707:Mypatent.publication_num_assignee`)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is missing a [`GROUP BY()` statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/count.php), as you are grouping the results by more than one column, while using `COUNT()`, which is an aggregate function.

Meanwhile, I invite you to review the [the standard SQL syntax for BigQuery](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax), you might want to particularly focus on [the `UNNEST` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest).